# Which media to use for backing up data of my laptop?

Tags: backup, storage, external-hdd, media

I work at home on my laptop installed with Windows 7 & Ubuntu 13.04. I have stopped working on Windows since much time & would continue to work on Linux only. I have all my important data in the laptop. I haven't yet used any external media for backup but now I feel the need for the same. Now, what media should I use?

I have the below considerations:

1. I have my own data like webpages, text docs, videos, audios etc.
2. I have videos & photos of my child which will obviously go on increasing with time. I was thinking to save these in DVDs but since a few months the DVDs I had been purchasing aren't getting burned. I yesterday got Verbatim DVDs from eBay.in but they also didn't work. Also how much trustworthy are DVDs !! I burned gparted on a Amkette DVD 4 months back & now it isn't working properly.
   I think DVDs aren't good options as the number of DVDs will go on increasing to keep backup of my baby's videos & much care needs to be taken  to keep it safely. In contrast external hdd is more safe & in 1 hdd only I can keep all these data along with my own. Also external hdd is more reliable than DVDs. HDDs will last for many many years but not DVDs.
3. DVDs are getting extinct; future devices may not have DVD drivers. So DVDs don't seem to be a good choice.
4. I think external HDDs can be used with any laptop or computer like flash drive (no external power required). It can be used irrespective of the OS whether Windows or Linux. I should be able to format it, create partitions of any filesystem type... In a nutshell, I can treat it in the same way as internal HDD & flash drive; i.e. external HDDs are only an extension of my laptops internal memory space. 
   I'm looking for this 'general' external device & not one that works with any specific s/w or h/w.

Please throw some light on these. I feel external HDDs are the best choice of backup media.

Comment: @slm As this Question is on hold, I'm writing this. Point no. 4 is not opinion based but based on facts.So I feel the Q can be released from being held so that one can comment on point number 4 & I can be benefited

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the external HDD. In my opinion you mentioned the most important points. May you could also think about a cloud-backup (dropbox, google drive, etc.).

To you thoughts about the external HDD I can just add, that the file system must be accessible by windows an linux (Maybe FAT32).

Comment: Thanks. Please comment on point no. 4 in my Q